# Angular - multiple subscribe don't get the same answer

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

i have a little problem, i subscribe to an observable 2 times.
On time i have the correct result but with my second subscribe, i always have the same result.
Here is my code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject, merge, EMPTY, combineLatest, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { scan, map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { boatsList } from 'src/app/shared/mocks/boats.mock';
import { CatamaranModel } from 'src/app/shared/models/catamaran.model';
import { SailBoatModel } from 'src/app/shared/models/sail-boat.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BoatListService {

  private boatListInitSubject: BehaviorSubject<(CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel)[]> = new BehaviorSubject(boatsList);
  boatListInit$ = this.boatListInitSubject.asObservable();

  private addedBoatSubject: Subject<(CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel)> = new Subject();
  addedBoat$ = this.addedBoatSubject.asObservable();

  boatList$: Observable<(CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel)[]> = merge(
    this.boatListInit$,
    this.addedBoat$
  )
    .pipe(
      scan((acc: (CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel)[], value: CatamaranModel|SailBoatModel) => [...acc, value]),
    );

  constructor() {
    this.addedBoat$.subscribe(data => console.log('DATA', data));
    this.boatList$.subscribe(data => console.log('DATA AFTER ADD', data));
  }

  addBoat(boat: CatamaranModel | SailBoatModel){
    this.addedBoatSubject.next(boat);
  }
}
```

In this code, the this.boatlist$.subscribe give me 5 objects in my array, which is good.

The addBoat is call like this :

```
 onSubmit(){
    if (this.addBoatForm.valid){
      this.boatListService.addBoat(
        new CatamaranModel(150, 150, 564, 15, false)
      );
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      console.log('BATEAU AJOUTE');
    }
  }
```

But in this code :

```
  constructor(
    private boatListService: BoatListService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.boatListService.boatList$.subscribe((data) => console.log('IN THE ADD COMPONENT', data));
  }
```

The subscribe is launching when it has to, but always send me the old value (the value used for the init).

I don't understand why i have two data for the same observable.

If someone has an idea...

Comment: At what point are you calling `addBoat()` of your service?

Comment: I edited my post, he is called once, and in the service, the data are good but in my component, the subscribe is launched but get the old data

Comment: You are changing route to Root on Submit, this would probably reInitialize your App and all your changes would be lost, so you would only have whhat you are initializing in Behavior subject(it gets reInitialized)

Comment: It's weird the navigation reinit all. How can i avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior of `boatListInitSubject` as it is a `BehaviorSubject`

> One of the variants of Subjects is the BehaviorSubject, which has a
>   notion of "the current value". It stores the latest value emitted to
>   its consumers, and whenever a new Observer subscribes, it will
>   immediately receive the "current value" from the BehaviorSubject.

Comment: Yes i know that, but boatList$ is an observable, not a subject. The problem should be for the 2 subscribe if it was the behaviourSubject, but only one as the good data

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved my problem,

After the adding, i redirect to another page in LazyLoading.

I had a problem in the module of this page (don't know exactly what because i deleted and recreate my module file) which relaunch my observable service each times this page was loaded.